# EF Core - Why are entities being saved as new DB entities when they should be Foreign Key Relationships?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api

Moving away from EF6 DB first models for our contexts - I'm building an ASP Core API that uses EF Core Code First model for database contexts. To do this in a rolling update, my contexts have to exist with the current DB schema so I'm using EF Fluent API to build my entity mappings for the Code First models that don't reflect the current database schema.

I'm hitting an issue with Navigation Properties on the entities during Insert operations. Getting the data from the DB for the primary entity works great using the standard .Include(x => x.OtherEntity) format, saving the primary entity back to the DB is where the problem lies.

Using the Fluent API to map entities is new for me, so the learning curve is likely where my issue lies. I've tried to work with OwnsOne vs. HasOne but the MS documentation suggests that HasOne() is the proper method of doing this mapping.

My main entity in question has Shadow Properties for the Foreign Key fields that key linked up when I use .HasOne() in the fluent mapping (in the code below)

The Exception Messages aren't useful in this case because they don't reflect a mapping issue, they suggest that data can't be inserted when the tables of the navigation properties have Identity Columns (I.E. can't insert a record with an explicit ID) -> This is odd because I'm not trying to insert data through those navigation properties, I'm just trying to link my main entity to that secondary entity with the Foreign Key.

Entity Mapping:

```
 // WorkOrder Entity Mapping:
 modelBuilder.Entity<WorkOrder>().ToTable("WorkOrder");
 modelBuilder.Entity<WorkOrder>().Property(x => x.Id).HasColumnName("IDWorkOrder");
  modelBuilder.Entity<WorkOrder>().Property(x => x.CreatedBy).HasColumnName("IDUserCreated");
  modelBuilder.Entity<WorkOrder>().Property(x => x.UpdatedBy).HasColumnName("IDUserUpdated");
  modelBuilder.Entity<WorkOrder>().Property<int?>("IDWOCategory");
  modelBuilder.Entity<WorkOrder>().Property<int?>("IDProblem");
  modelBuilder.Entity<WorkOrder>().Property<int?>("IDWOCostCenter");
  modelBuilder.Entity<WorkOrder>().Property<int?>("IDWOLocation");
  modelBuilder.Entity<WorkOrder>().Property<int?>("IDWOPriority");
  modelBuilder.Entity<WorkOrder>().Property<int?>("IDWOStatus");
  modelBuilder.Entity<WorkOrder>().Property<int?>("IDWOTrade");
  modelBuilder.Entity<WorkOrder>().Property<Guid?>("IDUserCompleted");
  modelBuilder.Entity<WorkOrder>().Property<Guid?>("IDParentWO");

  // WO Navigation Properties:
  modelBuilder.Entity<WorkOrder>().HasOne(x => x.Category).WithOne().HasForeignKey<WorkOrder>("IDWOCategory").HasPrincipalKey<Category>(c => c.Id);
  modelBuilder.Entity<WorkOrder>().HasOne(x => x.Problem).WithOne().HasForeignKey<WorkOrder>("IDProblem").HasPrincipalKey<Problem>(c => c.Id);
  modelBuilder.Entity<WorkOrder>().HasOne(x => x.CostCenter).WithOne().HasForeignKey<WorkOrder>("IDWOCostCenter").HasPrincipalKey<CostCenter>(c => c.Id);
  modelBuilder.Entity<WorkOrder>().HasOne(x => x.Location).WithOne().HasForeignKey<WorkOrder>("IDWOLocation").HasPrincipalKey<Location>(c => c.Id);
  modelBuilder.Entity<WorkOrder>().HasOne(x => x.Priority).WithOne().HasForeignKey<WorkOrder>("IDWOPriority").HasPrincipalKey<Priority>(c => c.Id);
  modelBuilder.Entity<WorkOrder>().HasOne(x => x.Status).WithOne().HasForeignKey<WorkOrder>("IDWOStatus").HasPrincipalKey<Status>(c => c.Id);
  modelBuilder.Entity<WorkOrder>().HasOne(x => x.Trade).WithOne().HasForeignKey<WorkOrder>("IDWOTrade").HasPrincipalKey<Trade>(c => c.Id);
  modelBuilder.Entity<WorkOrder>().HasOne(x => x.Requester).WithOne().HasForeignKey<WorkOrder>("IDRequester").HasPrincipalKey<Requester>(c => c.Id);
  modelBuilder.Entity<WorkOrder>().HasOne(x => x.UserCompleted).WithOne().HasForeignKey<WorkOrder>("IDUserCompleted").HasPrincipalKey<User>(c => c.Id);
  modelBuilder.Entity<WorkOrder>().HasOne(x => x.ParentWorkOrder).WithOne().HasForeignKey<WorkOrder>("IDParentWO").HasPrincipalKey<WorkOrder>(c => c.Id);
```

Getting the data in the controller: (Works like a charm!)

```
[HttpGet("{Id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<List<WorkOrder>>> GetWorkOrders(Guid Id)
{
    var result = await WorkOrdersContext.WorkOrders
        .Include(x => x.Problem)
        .Include(x => x.Status)
        .Include(x => x.Requester)
        .Include(x => x.ParentWorkOrder)
        .Include(x => x.Category)
        .Include(x => x.Trade)
        .Include(x => x.Location)
        .Include(x => x.CostCenter)
        .Include(x => x.Priority)
        .Where(x => x.Id == Id)
        .ToListAsync();

    return Ok(result);
}
```

Saving new Data in the controller: (Where it breaks down!)

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<WorkOrder>> CreateWorkOrderFromPending([FromBody]WorkOrder call)
{
    // Insert the Work Order to the DB:
    DbContext.WorkOrders.Add(call);
    var saveResult = await DbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

    // Check if any oddities occurred during the save:
    if (saveResult == 0) return BadRequest("An Error occurred during saving and the Call was not saved, please try again.");

    // Return the Inserted Work Order:
    return Ok(call);
}
```

Here, when it tries to save the new Work Order, it throws an exception because of the mapped types (Problem, Category, CostCenter, etc from the Entity Mappings code snippet) It's trying to save the data as new entities rather than building the FK relationship on existing entities. I think this is where I'm missing some logic with the Fluent API!

Any help would be greatly appreciated since it's quite hard to put this problem into a few words for a google search!

Comment: Nothing to do with the fluent API.  You Add()ed an object graph to the context, and all the objects will be marked as Added.  You can later change this through the change tracker, or use Attach() instead of Add(), which will set the objects to Unchanged, unless they have a null StoreGenerated key, in which case they will be set to Added.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft, excellent! Thank you for the info, I'll see if doing this does the trick!

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft - I retract that last statement! It's now working as expected, thank you so much for the input! Coming from a Code First background I've never had to do this with .Attach() and change the entity state but I guess trying to make EF Core coexist with DB First isn't exactly an easy or normal case either!

Again, thank you for the help!

Comment: Side note: All these `WithOne` look suspicious and may cause you future problems - it's unlikely all these FKs to be unique inside `WorkOrder` table. Consider changing them to `WithMany()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @DavidBrowne-Microsoft, I have the answer, trying to make the DB First stuff from our past coexist with .NET Core is no easy task and coming from a Code First background, where .Add() was the path that worked, made it hard to see how .Attach() was going to do the trick.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<WorkOrder>> CreateWorkOrderFromPending([FromBody]WorkOrder call)
{
    // Insert the Work Order to the DB:
    // DbContext.WorkOrders.Add(call);
    var entity = DbContext.WorkOrders.Attach(call);

    entity.State = EntityState.Added;

    var saveResult = await DbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

    // Check if any oddities occurred during the save:
    if (saveResult == 0) return BadRequest("An Error occurred during saving and the Call was not saved, please try again.");

    // Return the Inserted Work Order:
    return Ok(call);
}
```

Using .Attach() instead of .Add() did the trick, placing the entity in and mapping up the FKs to their respective Shadow Properties from my Fluent mappings!